# ExtJS upgrade Nightmare 4.2.2 to 5.1 TreePanel breaks (in compatibility mode)

Tags: extjs, upgrade, compatibility, mode

I am upgrading my ExtJS 4.2.2 based application to ExtJS 5.1 using Sencha Cmd.

I am unable to work with TreePanels in the application (the tree collapse functionality has stopped working)

**app.json**

```
"compatibility" : {
        "ext" : "4.2"
},
```

[image]

[image]

This has been identified as a bug [EXTJS-14927](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291376-Compatibility-mode-breaks-TreeStore) reported in Aug 2013. I am not sure what Sencha team is doing with this till date. They are busy making money in launching version 6 7... and 10 but couldn't fix this one till date.

Do we have someone who has found some alternative or a workaround? I will ve grateful.

Heard from the Sencha Support - https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291376-Compatibility-mode-breaks-TreeStore

Comment: Adding a "compatibility mode" was one of Senchas various good ideas which was implemented really badly and thus backfired. You are better off if you remove the compatibility mode and fix all bugs that arise afterwards. Once you have an application that works with 5.1.2, everything should get better. At least that was my feeling after upgrade - 5.1.2 and 6.0.1 seem far more stable and less error-prone than 4.2.x.

Comment: Big Help. Exactly what I needed to hear. I had actually started working on this direction. Thanks much :)